# Prove that $T$ is a tree of order $n$ if and only if $T$ is a connected graph with size $n-1$.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Prove that $T$ is a tree of order $n$ if and only if $T$ is a connected graph with size $n-1$.

Here is my answer.

Proof: ($\Rightarrow$) Let $T$ be a tree of order $n$ and let the size of $T$ be $m$. By definition, $T$ is connected. Also $n = m + 1\implies m = n - 1$, so the tree has size $n - 1$.

($\Leftarrow$) Let $T$ be a connected graph with size $n-1$. It suffices to show that $T$ is acyclic or has no cycles. If $T$ contains a cycle $c$, and $e$ is an edge of $c$, then $T-e$ is a connected graph of order $n$ having size $n-2$, which is impossible. Therefore $T$ is acyclic or has no cycles. Thus, $T$ is a tree.

I am not sure my answer is good so I am just wondering if I can get some feedback if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you are assuming the result you want to prove in both cases. For $\Rightarrow$, how do you know $n=m+1$? For $\Leftarrow$, why is it impossible for a connected graph of order $n$ to have $n-2$ edges?

Comment: Thearem 4.4 Every tree of order n has size n-1.
Theorem 4.3 Every nontrvial tree has at least two end-vertices
There is only one tree of order 1, namely K1 which has size 0. Thus the result is true for n = 1. We assume for a positive interger k that the size of every tree of order k is k-1. Let T be a tree of order k+1 and by them 4.3, T contains at least two end-vertices. Let v be one of them. Then T' = T-v is a tree of order k. The size of T' is m = k-1 and since T has exactly one more edge than T',the size of T is m +1 = (k-1) + 1 = (k+1) - 1.

Comment: Is this what I should mention in my prove to clarify?

Comment: If a graph has fewer than n−1 edges, it reduced the number of components by at most n−2  from n, so it has at least two components, and is not connected.If a graph has more than n−1 edges and is a tree, then it reduced the number of components by at least n from n, so it has at most zero components, which is impossible.  Therefore, a tree must haven−1 edges.

Comment: @KrisLetang Yes, with those extra details it looks good.